# sed replace between two strings wildcard

Tags: regex, bash, sed, wildcard, non-greedy

I am trying to flag everything inside a color tag and replace it with something else, such as:

```
I have a [color=blue]dog[/color] and a [color=blue]cat[/color] in my house.
```

to

```
I have a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] and a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] in my house.
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
sample='I have a [color=blue]dog[/color] and a [color=blue]cat[/color] in my house.'
replace='foobar'
sample=$(echo $sample| sed "s/\[color=blue\].*\[\/color\]/\[color=blue\]\[b\]$replace\[\/b\]\[\/color\]/g")
```

Which gets me:

```
I have a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] in my house.
```

Any idea on how to make sed nongreedy in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `.*` with `[^[]*` (any character other than left bracket).  That is:

```
"s/\[color=blue\][^[]*\[\/color\]/\[color=blue\]\[b\]$replace\[\/b\]\[\/color\]/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is always greedy.  You can work around it by selecting the regex carefully.  The example below is identical to yours except that `.*` has been replaced with `[^[]*` (which means everything *except* `[`):

```
$ echo $sample| sed "s/\[color=blue\][^[]*\[\/color\]/\[color=blue\]\[b\]$replace\[\/b\]\[\/color\]/g"
I have a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] and a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] in my house.
```

For truly non-greedy regular expressions, try perl or python.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sed 's#\(\[color=[[:alpha:]]*\]\)[[:alnum:]]*\(\[/color\)#\1[b]foobar[/b]\2#g'
```

example

```
echo 'I have a [color=blue]dog[/color] and a [color=blue]cat[/color] in my house.'|sed 's#\(\[color=[[:alpha:]]*\]\)[[:alnum:]]*\(\[/color\)#\1[b]\2#g'
```

output

```
  I have a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] and a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] in my house.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(\[color=[a-z]*\])[a-z]*(\[\/color\])/\1[b]foobar[\/b]\2/g' File
```

or

```
sed 's/\(\[color=[a-z]*\]\)[a-z]*\(\[\/color\]\)/\1[b]foobar[\/b]\2/g' File
```

**Explanation:**
Here, we look for the patterns `1. [color=any small letter sequence]` followed by `2. any small letter sequence` followed by `3. [/color]` and group patterns `1 and 3` using `(` and `)`. Then we do the substitutions. We keep the `1st and 2nd groups` (using `\1` and `\2`), but replace the contents between the first and second group with `[b]foobar[/b]`.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Could you give explanation for your code?

Comment: @A.M.D you dont have to backslash things in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

---

As other have stated you need to use non greedy by reading non matching characters.

Using a carat inside brackets `[^ABC]` effectively means not whatever follows.

So using this with the asterix `*` will match only up to the next one of that character.

---

For example

```
[^[]*
```

Will match everything up to the next `[` bracket

Also everyone is backslash escaping the replacement which is not needed as it cannot print regex.

Anyway here is a command that should work.

```
sed 's/\(\[color[^]]*\]\)[^[]*\(\[\/color\]\)/\1[b]foobar\[b]\2/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` will always be greedy. You can use `perl` if you strictly want non-greedy variant:

```
$ echo $test
I have a [color=blue]dog[/color] and a [color=blue]cat[/color] in my house.

$ perl -pne 's/(\[color=[a-zA-Z]*\])(.*?)(\[\/color\])/$1\[b\]foobar\[\/b\]$3/g' <<< "$test"
I have a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] and a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] in my house.
```

I guess, you can interpret most of the regex here, except for the tiny syntax change:
`(.*?)` in place of `(.*)` dictates that the match is supposed to be non-greedy.
If you skip `?` after `.*`, here is the output you must be getting currently:

```
$ perl -pne 's/(\[color=[a-zA-Z]*\])(.*)(\[\/color\])/$1\[b\]foobar\[\/b\]$3/g' <<< "$test"
I have a [color=blue][b]foobar[/b][/color] in my house.
```